# Git Merging Issue two branches

Tags: git, merge

I am new in git and have problem in merging.
Scenario :

I have a master branch. I create new branch dev from master start commits in dev branch . After two days I create new branch devmerge from dev branch . Now one team was start working on devmerge and one was on dev. Now dev is also some commit history and devmerge is also some commit history but the problem is when I want to merge both devmerge to dev the result missed the some commit history of dev (some dev data is missed) . I don't know what is happening .

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest trying it in distinct stages.

```
Master ---------------------
  \-----Dev-----------------
              \-DevMerge----
```

You have the above, perform each merge separately:

```
git checkout dev
git merge devmerge
```

Resulting in:

```
Master --------------------------
  \-----Dev------------------m1--
              \-DevMerge----/
```

Where `m1` is the merge commit.

```
git checkout master
git merge dev
```

Resulting in:

```
Master ----------------------------m2------
  \-----Dev------------------m1---/
              \-DevMerge----/
```

I'd recommend installing a [tool such as `gitg`](http://git-scm.com/downloads/guis) depending on the platform you're using, to get a visual representation of the branches.

Comment: hi bcmcfc thanks for quick response but issue is , dev is also has some commit history after devmerge creation. means in both branches developers commits their work now both branches are working branches but now when i merge devmerge into dev some dev files are replaced with devmerge files ,code is overridden although we have changed these files in dev.For explanation I have a file gameconfig.cpp , i changed some lines in dev branch when i merge devmerge into dev this file changes replaced by old devmerge code .